# Why does this JavaScript assignment not raise an error: const a = (1, 2, 3, 4);

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, parentheses

```js
const a = (1, 2, 3, 4);
console.log(a);

const b = 1, 2, 3, 4;
console.log(b);
```

In the above example, `a` will be assigned the value `4`, while the second line will raise an error. Why does the first assignment "succeed". Why is it valid JS syntax?

Comment: The first assigns the result of an expression to `a`. The second is a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma operator returns the last expression listed. It works in the first case because it is parenthesized and parsed as a single expression. However, once a valid expression is finished after a `=` - in the second case, `1` - and the next token is a comma, JavaScripts expects another identifier to declare, so you can declare multiple variables like this:

```js
let a = 1, b = 2;
```